Can you make the following "coinductive" proof precise?
Question: I have a proof which overwhelmingly feels like it's a proof "by coinduction." Unfortunately I can't coinduct my way out of a paper bag, so I don't know if this actually works. I have reproduced the proof below, using the term "coinduction" informally. My question is, can it be made precise? Thanks very much!

Suppose $X$ is an infinite set and $\mathcal{F}$ is an infinite family of subsets of $X$. Then there is a pair of sequences $(x_0,x_1,\dots)$ from $X$ and $(F_0,F_1,\dots)$ from $\mathcal{F}$ such that for every $i < j$, $F_i$ and $F_j$ disagree on $x_i$ and agree on $x_k$ for every $k < i$. (We say that two sets disagree on an object if that object is in their symmetric difference.)
One may justify this as follows. For $x \in X$, let $\mathcal{F}_x$ and $\mathcal{F}_\bar{x}$ be the subfamilies of $\mathcal{F}$ that include and exclude $x$ respectively. For each $x$, one of these will be infinite. For some $x$, both will be nonempty (since there are at least two sets in $\mathcal{F}$).
This means that we can always find an element $x_0 \in X$, a set $F_0 \in \mathcal{F}$, and an infinite family $\mathcal{G \subset F}$ such that $F_0$ disagrees on $x_0$ with everything in $\mathcal{G}$ and (therefore) any pair of sets in $\mathcal{G}$ agrees on $x_0$. That gives us the heads of our two sequences $x_0$ and $F_0$. Coinductively construct the tails $(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ and $(F_1,F_2,\dots)$ from $\mathcal{G}$. Notice that $F_0$ disagrees with $F_j$ for any $0 < j$ on $x_0$, and for any $0 < i < j$, $F_i$ and $F_j$ agree on $x_0$. The rest follows by coinduction.

We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See here and here. Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.

This looks like a question about pure math.  In what way is this on-topic for CS?  Why does it need to be answered from a computer science perspective, rather than as a matter of mathematics?

I'm not asking whether my proof is correct---it certainly is---but rather how it can be formalized using coinduction. (I can easily give a precise inductive proof.) I imagine the answer will be of broad interest to anyone learning the technique. It's on-topic for CS because I believe coinduction is more well known amongst the academic CS community. That said, if you still believe this question is inappropriate, I'll happily remove it.
